# NestJS mongoose return info from the database

Tags: database, mongodb, api, mongoose, nestjs

So, when i get the info from the MongoDB database in a NestJS service, i want to return it to the controller and send it to the client (Angular)

I tried returning it with a `Promise` but i cant get it working.

Heres my code with the thing a tried:

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import mongoose, { Model } from "mongoose";
import {
  FriendRequest,
  FriendRequestDocument,
} from "../schema/friend-requests.schema";
import { Users, UsersDocument } from "../schema/user.schema";
import { FriendsDto } from "./dto/friends.dto";

@Injectable()
export class AddFriendService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Users.name) private readonly usersModel: Model<UsersDocument>,
    @InjectModel("friendRequests")
    private readonly friendrequestModel: Model<FriendRequestDocument>
  ) {}

  async getRequests(userid: string) {
    
    
    let incomingrqs = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let response = {
          incoming: [],
        };
        this.friendrequestModel
        .aggregate([
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "author",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "userdata",
                // pipeline: [
                //   {
                //     $match: {
                //       friend_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid)
                //     }
                //   }
                // ],
              },
            },
          ])
          .exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
    
            if (!data) {
              console.log("No data returned");
            }
    
            data.forEach((rqsData) => {
              response.incoming.push({
                userid: rqsData.userdata[0]._id,
                username: rqsData.userdata[0].username,
                created_at: rqsData.userdata[0].created_at,
                pfp: "/assets/cdn/pfp/" + rqsData.userdata[0].pfp,
              });
            });
          });

          resolve(response);
      })

      incomingrqs.then(x => {
        return x;
      })
  }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
import { Get, Controller, Body, Post, Param } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AddFriendService } from "./friends.service";
import { FriendsDto } from "./dto/friends.dto";

@Controller("friends")
export class AddFriendController {
  constructor(private friendsService: AddFriendService) {}

  @Post("rqs")
  async getRqs(@Body() friendsDto: FriendsDto){

    let rqs = await this.friendsService.getRequests(friendsDto.userid);
    console.log(rqs)
    return rqs;
  }
}
```

**FriendRequestDocument:**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import mongoose, { Document, ObjectId } from "mongoose";

export type FriendRequestDocument = FriendRequest & Document;

@Schema({collection: "friendRequests"})
export class FriendRequest {
  @Prop()
  author: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  friend_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  request_at: Date;
}

export const FriendRequestSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(FriendRequest);
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`aggregate.exec` can already return a `promise` if no callback is given](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec), just FYI.

You need to return the `incomingrqs` to the controller. [This is standard of how promises work.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Returning inside the `then` forwards the return on to the *next* promise, which is why the `incomingrqs` needs to be `return`ed as well. Otherwise, the controller will never know what the service returns.